# Selecting ranges in VBA the same way Excel does

Tags: excel, vba

I've noticed that Excel does not use the RefEdit control to select ranges.

Instead, it seems that Excel uses its own control:
[image: Excel own control]

But then when we are developing a VBA form, we can only use the RefEdit control:
[image: RefEdit]

So my question is, can we use the Excel control (used to select ranges) in our VBA form?
[image: Excel control in VBA form?]

Many thanks!

Comment: No, you can't I'm afraid.

Comment: I have written a class that mimicks Excel's range dialog pretty closely. I don't know how to post the workbook here though.